# How to import polymer html files from outside the site in a Polymer and firebase project

Tags: polymer

Newest progression: 
It seems that I can exclude firebase from possible causes. Because I tested only with polymer deployment and got a bad result too.

My project uses Google Polymer and is deployed to firebase hosting. It needs to import some polymer html file from outside the firebase hosting.
So I changed the code from the following "local" to "outside". However "outside" does not work at all, where "local" means my local computer for testing or the firebase hosting.
Could you point out what is wrong in my code?

my-app.html has one of following links.

```
    //"local: OK"
    <link rel="import" href="some.html">
    //"outside: not OK"
    <link rel="import" href="https://outside.com/some.html">
```

And my-app.html uses the element, id="some", as

```
    <template><some></some></template>
```

And "some.html" contains just one dom-module with the following simple template. Let me omitt writting other parts because they are minimum too.

```
    <template><h1>test</h1></template>
```

Comment: Do you have a demo (jsbin/codepen/plunker) of this? What errors are shown in your browser console?

Comment: @tony, your comment made me realize that my project is not just a Polymer project but a firebase and polymer project. I revised the question.

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the imported polymer html, some.html, has just a simple content, <h1>test</h1>. And it appears when tested with href to local whereas not when tested with hre to outside the deployed site.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, resources on other origins must be CORS-enabled (cross origin resource sharing) as [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#basics) states. The [W3C draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/#fetching-import) on HTML imports also mentions it.

The [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) tag also has a `crossorigin` attribute, which may help here. E.g. `<link rel="import" href="https://outside.com/some.html" crossorgin="anonymous">`.